# Автоматически перезаписывается htaccess, при удалении снова появляется

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-плагины

Сайт на wordpress, в cpanel редактирую htaccess,пишет файл сохранен, захожу заново, а там опять старый код, а при удалении htaccess он появляется опять. Деактивировал плагин Wp rocket, не помогло.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/why-does-wordpress-3-0-4-keep-deleting-the-contents-of-the-htaccess-file тут пишут, что wp всегда пытается переписать htaccess если в админке установлены постоянные ссылки permalink

Answer (score 0):

> Сайт на wordpress, в cpanel редактирую htaccess,пишет файл сохранен,
>   захожу заново, а там опять старый код,

ВП перезаписывает только секцию

```
# BEGIN WordPress
..
# END WordPress
```

Если ты правишь внутри неё - то всё верно, так и должно быть.
Вноси изменения вне её.